# jqGrid: Subgrid row displaying columns obtained in maingrid json

Tags: jqgrid, subgrid

Can I have a subgrid that shows some of the columns from main grid without actually going and getting data again using URL?
Example:Main Grid is getting data from server (10 columns) using jsonReader out of which I want to show 7 columns in the parent row and 3 columns in the subgrid row . Can I do this?
(Or some other way to achieve this expand concept?)

(I tried the below with "subGridRowExpanded" function but it doesn't seem to be working...)

Error: jQuery("#grid").getRowData is not a function

```
-------------------------------------
var myGrid =  jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({

...
subGrid: true,

subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
            var subgridTableId = subgridDivId + "_t";
            var rowData = $("#grid").getRowData(rowId);
            var requestorFullName = rowData['requestorFullName'];
             var html ="<table id='" + subgridTableId + "'> <tr><td>'" +requestorFullName+"'</td></tr> </table>";
             $("#" + subgridDivId).append(html);

}

});

-------------------------------------
```

Comment: Got it to work.Had to make the following change: var rowData = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getRowData', rowId)

Comment: Can anyone comment if this way of creating the table and showing around 5 to 7 fields will be a performance hit for a large table?